# SQL join beween tables with if statement

Tags: sql

Say, I have the following two tables:
Table customer:

```
id, salutation, forename, lastname, companyID
```

and a table company:

```
Company_id, Company_name, Company_address
```

and I want to have an evaluation over all users and their company (if they belong to one)

```
salutation, forename, lastname, companyName
```

that would amount basically to a very easy script:

```
select salutation, forename, lastname, company_name
from customer, company
where companyID=Company_id;
```

The trouble now is just, that companyID can be null. (A customer doesn't need to be part of a company).  And since there is no companyID null entry in the company table and any customer who has no company ID listed is omitted due to the joint statement.

Of couse I could divide it into two scripts one for companyid=null and one for not null and mix them with a UNION command, but is there perhaps something like an if statement?

something like:

```
select salutation, forename, lastname, placeholder
from customer, company
where 
if companyID=null then placeholder=null 
else (companyID=Company_id and placeholder=company_name);
```

?

I know there is a case statement, that can check on the field's value and return something else instead, but is there a way to combine that with a joint to another table?

Comment: U cant use a sql query along with a if condition.

Comment: Would a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` solve your problem?

Comment: select z.salutation, z.forename, z.lastname, x.company_name
from customer z
left join company x on z.companyID = x.Company_id;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an outer join:

```
select cu.salutation, cu.forename, cu.lastname, co.company_name
from customer cu
  left join company co on cu.companyID = co.Company_id;
```

In general you should stop using the ancient implicit join syntax in the `where` clause and use an explicit `JOIN` operator. That is also the only cross-DBMS way to actually *do* an outer join (all DBMS that supported some proprietary outer join syntax have deprecated that)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select salutation, forename, lastname, placeholder
from customer, company
where 
(companyID=null and placeholder=null )
OR
(companyID=Company_id and placeholder=company_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join instead of an inner join

```
select a.salutation, a.forename, a.lastname, a.company_name
from customer a
left outer join company b
on a.companyID=b.companyID;
```